# ASP.NET session object generates InvalidCastException when trying to do a "valid" cast

Tags: asp.net, session, casting

in a method I store a struct into HttpSession:

```
  HttpContext.Current.Session["search_headers"] = ra;
```

where ra is my custom struct of type "replySearchAjax".

In a webmethod, that belongs to same namespace, I am trying to do:

```
   [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public replySearchAjax RestorePhenSearchTable()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["search_headers"] != null)
        {
            replySearchAjax aa =  (replySearchAjax) HttpContext.Current.Session["search_headers"];
            return aa;
        }
```

but the line with typecast returns

```
{"Message":"Specified cast is not valid." 
 "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidCastException"}
```

Examination of session variable at breakpoint at the line that produces exception shows that inside it are valid replySearchAjax fields.

How I would make it work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a struct? Do you get the same error if you change replySearchAjax to a class?

Comment: @JasonP, did not help. :) Simliar typecase error.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that "ra" is the right type when you store it in the first place? Can you set a breakpoint at that first line of code in your question and check?